# Git tag command for creating tag from a particular branch

Tags: git, gitlab

What command is used in background by gitlab for creating tag from a particular branch as mentioned in the Image and not from head/master/latest commit.  Require that command to write in batch file.

[image: Screenshot of Gitlab]

Using git tag -a release/231/P03HF00 -m "ARM 2.3.2 Patch#0" Command creates the tag from master, but how to specify the branch name also in the above command.

Since gitlab is providing the option then there must be some git commands that is running in background

Comment: Have you read the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag)?

Comment: Hint: last param of the [command synopsis](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_synopsis) : `[<commit> | <object>]`

Answer (score 2):

[`git help tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag):

```
git tag [-a | -s | -u <key-id>] [-f] [-m <msg> | -F <file>] [-e]
    <tagname> [<commit> | <object>]
```

> […], a tag reference that points directly at the given object (i.e., a lightweight tag) is created.

Which means that `git tag mytag somebranch` will tag the current head commit of branch `somebranch` with the new tag `mytag`. The object can be a branch, a commit, another tag, a tree, or a blob.

If you require an annotated tag with message, then:

```
git tag -a release/231/P03HF00 -m "ARM 2.3.2 Patch#0" release/231P01
```